# Extracting main directory from path using Regex in Hive

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I am using regex function in Hive to find the main folder.

I want to parse out "main" from this file path:

```
/main/one/path/to/hdfs
```

This is the regex which I used:

```
regexp_extract(filepath,'(^/[^/]+)',0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the "/" with a "\"

`(^\/[^\/]+)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that we wish to get the first directory after slash, which we might want to start with this simple expression:

```
\/(.+?)\/.+
```

Here, we are having our `main` output captured in this first capturing group:

```
(.+?)
```

which we can simply call it using group `1`, and our code would likely look like:

```
regexp_extract(filepath,'\/(.+?)\/.+', 1)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fvV3lO/1/)